# object required error in vba for assigining a value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub NewNightLetter()
Dim NewFile As String
WorkBookPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
ProgramSelected = DataPuller.Home.Range("F4").Value
Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(WorkBookPath & "\" & ProgramSelected)
NewFile = ProgramSelected & "_PT Metrics_" & Format(Date, YYYYMMDD) & "xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (mySource & " \ " & NewFile)
End Sub
```

Here on 4 th line i am getting an error saying "object required". And when i code it like,

```
ProgramSelected=Workbooks(datapuller).Sheets(Home).Range("F4").Value
```

"Subscript out of range" error occures...Can u help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

Replace this part of your code

```
ProgramSelected = DataPuller.Home.Range("F4").Value
```

With this:

```
ProgramSelected = Workbooks("DataPuller").Sheets("Home").Range("F4").Value
```

or this to improve flexibility.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Workbooks("DataPuller").Sheets("Home")
ProgramSelected = ws.Range("F4").Value
```

Also take note that DataPuller workbook should be open.
You'll get `Subscript Out of Range` error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to workbook or worksheet by name, enclose it with double quote

`ProgramSelected=Workbooks("datapuller").Sheets("Home").Range("F4").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `datapuller` and  `Home` as string where `datapuller` refers to workbook name and `home` refers to sheet name. Below syntax will work.

```
Dim datapuller As String
    datapuller = "Book2"

    Dim Home As String
    Home = "sheet1"

    ProgramSelected = Workbooks(datapuller).Sheets(Home).Range("F4").Value
```